# An ideal op amp is given (with infinity gain), what is the current flowing through all the resistance for the given circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics

[image]

my problem is that do the output terminal of the op-amp behaves like short circuit of output terminal of the op-amp to its reference ground as shown in the ideal op-amp internal circuit?

[image]
[image]

Comment: short circuit of o/p terminal of the op-amp to its reference ground as shown in the ideal op-amp internal circuit

Comment: The diagram doesn't show a short circuit to ground. It shows a _[voltage source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source)_. The sine-wave symbol on the source tells you that its output is not a contstant voltage, and the equation above it tells you that the output voltage is a linear function of the difference between the two input voltages.

Comment: please consider that op-amp (in the circuit) is energized with +Vsupply and -Vsupply as shown in the ideal op-amp circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *unclear* from those diagrams how **current** flows from the op amp output pin back to ground. Current *must* flow in a complete loop, which involves the +DC supply, and the -DC supply going to the op amp.

So let's take your example 10 ohm circuit and see where current flows. There will be one amp of current flowing in this circuit. Your ideal op amp will maintain its output voltage at zero volts (because its two input pins will be at 0V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjQa0h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One amp flows through the 10V supply (V1), through R1 and into the op amp output pin. From there, it continues through the op amp to the -DC supply (which is grounded). That's a complete loop. No current flows through R2, and no current flows through R3.
 No current would flow through the +ve supply in this ideal case. In a *real* op amp, internal circuits draw a little extra current from its DC supplies.

Comment: yeah right, thanks bro.     In general, I assume that op-amp is energized with +ve and -ve, which generally, many books don't show. so as I didn't show. Actually I was using Lt-Spice in which, ideal op-amp model is not available. Well, thanks for "circuit lab".  Bro, can I have an upvote for the question.